# Framework catches exception in IEditableObject.EndEdit

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

If an exception is thrown in IEditableObject.EndEdit (when set from the WPF Datagrid using binding).

The exception is catched by the framework and this message is shown in the console "A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' ..".

I would actually like this exception to be more explicit as I "handle" all unhandled exception using DispatcherUnhandledException and AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException. Where I log the exception and inform the user before closing the app.

Do I need to use some kind of hack, like adding try-catch to each EndEdit and rethrow the exception using Application.Dispatcher ?

Comment: What are you binding to `DataGrid.ItemSource`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing

```
public class Editable : NotificationObject, IEditableObject
{
...
    public void EndEdit()
    {
            try
            {
                ...
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ExceptionUtils.ThrowOnUIThread(e);
            }
        }
    }
}


public static class ExceptionUtils
{
    public static void ThrowOnUIThread(Exception exception)
    {
        exception.PreserveStackTrace();
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { throw exception; }));
    }
}
```

About PreserveStackTrace see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351333/c-sharp-rethrow-an-exception-how-to-get-the-exception-stack-in-the-ide).